# Getting child elements from list of String paths

Tags: java, string, algorithm

If I have a list of String paths

```
Mammal/

Mammal/Pet/

Mammal/Pet/Dog/

Mammal/Pet/Cat/

Bird/

Bird/Blah/

Bird/Blah/Parrot/

Bird/Blah/Parrot/Feather/
```

and I only want the child-most elements

```
Mammal/Pet/Dog/

Mammal/Pet/Cat/

Bird/Blah/Parrot/Feather/
```

how would I do that better than I currently am doing?

My current code is not very well-written but it does work

```
List<String> paths = ...;
List<String> children = new ArrayList<String>();
if(paths.size()==1){children.add(paths.get(0));}
for(int i=1; i < paths.size(); i++){
    //Found a local maximum in number of "/"'s
    if(paths.get(i).split("/").length <= paths.get(i-1).split("/").length){
        children.add(paths.get(i-1));
    }
    else if(i==paths.size()-1){
        children.add(paths.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens the strings you write come randomly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Files.walkFileTree(), adding the "leaf" directories as you go along. Arguments are the starting path and a SimpleFileVisitor implementation.  The visitor simply checks the files within the current directory, and if none of the files are directories themselves, the directory is added to the set of paths.

```
Path start = Paths.get(...); // e.g. directory.getCanonicalPath()
Set<Path> leafDirectories = new HashSet<>();
Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        File[] subdirectories = dir.toFile().listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                return pathname.isDirectory();
            }
        });
    
        if (subdirectories.length == 0)
            leafDirectories.add(dir);
    
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
// print leaf directories
leafDirectories.stream().forEach(dir -> System.out.println(dir));
```